# How to change DPI of image in java?

Tags: java, image

I am trying to change the DPI of image but i am not able to change the default DPI of image.
so please suggest me how to change dpi of image.

Here is the offending code snippet:

```
 File inputFile = new File(inputImagePath);
    BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(inputFile);
   BufferedImage thumbImg = Scalr.resize(img, Method.QUALITY,Mode.FIT_TO_HEIGHT,720,Scalr.OP_DARKER);
    ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ImageIO.write(thumbImg,"jpg",os);
    String formatName = outputImagePath.substring(outputImagePath
            .lastIndexOf(".") + 1);
```

Comment: It's generally considered bad practice to completely change a question (see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/290297/1428606 and http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252113/1428606). Please consider rolling back to the original question, and then ask a new question, now that your problem is a different one.

Answer (score -1):

In your example you read the Image from .jpg file - you could simply use this.

In all other instances, you can probably get the binary data of itext image by calling

```
  byte [] data = image.getOriginalData ();
```

Once you have that you can use ImageIO to read the image and save it with another format if required.

Maybe like this:

```
File outputFile = new File("image.jpg");
try (InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream (data)) {
    BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(is);
    try (OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(outputFile)) {
        ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", os);
    } 
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: You mean like scaling? Please edit your question what you really want to do.

Comment: yes i mean Scaling , i want t change default DPI of image.

Comment: For use in pdg output  (usimg itext) or for what purpuse? Scaling can be done on the BufferedImage directly...

Comment: No i want to save image as 'jpg' and want to set DPI 72f  (resolution)